# Lazy loading and Eager Loading in Entity Framework .Net are showing same (confusing) behaviour

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading, eager-loading

i have tried to implement concepts of lazy and Eager loading in .Net Entity Framework. 
I have two tables Products & Categories, a category can have multiple products.
Please check attached screenshot.

1. **Default behavior [Lazy Loading true]**

[image: It shows all Categories and its related products as well. But as per definition it should get only categories at this time.]

2. **Eager Loading [Lazy Loading false] without keyword include**
   [image: In Eager loading it should load all Categories and Products in one query. But here it brought only categories but no products. This is totally different from its definition. (may be due to missing include keyword)]
3. **Eager Loading [Lazy Loading false] with keyword include**
   [image: Again this loaded all categories and its products, this is correct behavior of Eager loading but what is the different in results in this case and in Lazy load (Picture 1)]

In Lazy load it always load Categories and related products (whether we use include or not) . which is not correct. Please clarify me for this confusion.

Comment: In your last sentence, did you mean to say "In Eager load it always...."?

Comment: No @DavidG, its Lazy load. Actually i am facing this issue. Lazy loading load all Categories and products which shouldn't be

Comment: Lazy load will always load anything though, even viewing in the debugger will cause things to load.

Comment: Use SQL Profiler to see when the query to load the related data executed

Comment: Okay @DavidG, But how can i see the actual difference if i want to see. Can we see difference in SQL query generated for this LINQ code?

Comment: That's a completely different question though.

Comment: @Gerry Inspect `objDb.Products.Local` after your request. If eager loading includes the products already, you'll see them there. If lazy loading loads the products on demand, this doesn't qualify as demand, and you won't see the products there.

Comment: @hvd perfect... This seems correct. In case of Lazy Products.Local = 0 but in case of Eager Products.Local = 12 . it seems correct. Is Product.Local the loaded objects ?

Comment: @Gerry Yes, `objDb.Products.Local` is all the products that are available locally. That means either already loaded, or newly added, but you're not adding any new products in your code.

Comment: Thanks @hvd. Its clear now. Thanks for this valuable info. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In Lazy load it always load Categories and related products (whether
>   we use include or not) . which is not correct

Actually you don't load them in your *code*, it's the **debugger** that requests them to load, as you are currently viewing the list of the properties of your entities.

Comment: Okay, it means when I'll see resuts using debugger it request to load related entities in Lazy load. Right ?

Comment: @Gerry Yes: the debugger tries to access the navigation properties to display them, so it executes a new SQL request to lazy load those properties

Comment: Can we trace SQL requests in this case using VS or SQL Management studio ?

Comment: @Gerry Yes. Personally I use [SQL Server Profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) to do the job. It's a built-in tool provided with SQL Server and Management Studio.

Comment: @Gerry you can (not with express sql management studio though) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx

Comment: @ken2k what are the odds :p

Comment: @AlexanderDerck Yeah :D

Comment: @AlexanderDerck Nowadays, the Express version also includes the profiler. I think it was SQL Server 2012 SP1 that first provided it, but 2014 definitely has it.

Comment: @hvd oh nice! I didn't know that

Answer (score 2):

I think all works as expected, but you don't see it. In case of LazyLoading initial loaded only Categories, but when you debug your code and want to see Products - they loaded only at **this** moment and very quickly and you not observe difference.

Comment: Okay @Slava. it there any way to see the difference. i  means the difference in back end quires generated for this linq code?

Comment: First, try to look at variable _query_ without ToList() postfix: `var query = objDb.Categories` in case of LazyLoading (you won't see anything about Products).  Also if you use MS SQL you can try to use ms sql profiler.